# How to reposition the second string of each line to start at the nth character on the same line

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Ubuntu 16.04
Bash V 4.4

Here is my file:

```
4u76kumtstring5="${ThisLine__4u76kumtstring5}" # this vreis ethees 445h45thb ervexplanation forevrev
wevdssdstring6="${ThisLine__wevdssdstring6}" # this is theerve explanationver for wevdssdstring6 kj
rjjstring7="${ThisLine__rjjstring7}" # thise isder evervthe explanation for rjjstring7 eji
5trstring8="${ThisLine__5trstring8}" # this is ververthe explanation for 5trstring8 k8bf2kl
```

If I use column -t I get something like this:

```
4u76kumtstring5="${ThisLine__4u76kumtstring5}"  #  this   vreis  ethees     445h45thb       ervexplanation  forevrev
wevdssdstring6="${ThisLine__wevdssdstring6}"    #  this   is     theerve    explanationver  for             wevdssdstring6  kj
rjjstring7="${ThisLine__rjjstring7}"            #  thise  isder  evervthe   explanation     for             rjjstring7      eji
5trstring8="${ThisLine__5trstring8}"            #  this   is     ververthe  explanation     for             5trstring8      k8bf2kl
```

I want the second string to start the nth character of the line

```
4u76kumtstring5="${ThisLine__4u76kumtstring5}"               # this vreis ethees 445h45thb ervexplanation forevrev
wevdssdstring6="${ThisLine__wevdssdstring6}"                 # this is theerve explanationver for wevdssdstring6 kj
rjjstring7="${ThisLine__rjjstring7}"                         # thise isder evervthe explanation for rjjstring7 eji
5trstring8="${ThisLine__5trstring8}"                         # this is ververthe explanation for 5trstring8 k8bf2kl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there can't be a `#` in the leading `name="$variable"` part of each line:

```
$ awk -v n=60 '{h=$0; sub(/[[:space:]]*#.*/,"",h); sub(/[^#]+/,""); printf "%-*s%s\n", n, h, $0}' file
4u76kumtstring5="${ThisLine__4u76kumtstring5}"              # this vreis ethees 445h45thb ervexplanation forevrev
wevdssdstring6="${ThisLine__wevdssdstring6}"                # this is theerve explanationver for wevdssdstring6 kj
rjjstring7="${ThisLine__rjjstring7}"                        # thise isder evervthe explanation for rjjstring7 eji
5trstring8="${ThisLine__5trstring8}"                        # this is ververthe explanation for 5trstring8 k8bf2kl
```

Count the spaces to see if `60` is the right number, massage to suit.

Answer (score 1):

Give this awk one-liner a try:

```
awk -v n='60' -F'#' '{printf "%-*s#%s\n",n,$1,$2}' file
```

You can change the `n='60'` into other values.

Comment: This puts the hash in column 61.

Comment: That would delete anything after a second `#`, e.g. `foo   # we're #1!` would become ```foo   # we're ```.

Comment: @Kent Ed is right. I don't have scenario atm, but I do see it being introduced here shortly. Netherless, I appreciate t he help.

Answer (score 0):

Pure Bash -

```
c2=$columnYouWantTheHash
while IFS='#' read -r a b; do printf "%-$((c2-1))s%s\n" "$a" "#$b"; done < file
```

Comment: Caveat - if your last line has no newline, you'll need to account for that. I assume the first column can't have embedded hashes.

Comment: Truth. I was very careless to embed `$b` in the format. Edited.

Comment: /headsmack - added. Thanks, Ed.